# Бронирование услуг в календаре по фильтру

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, календарь

Здравствуйте, ищу календарь, в котором можно создавать ивенты, и количество мест в ивенте будет ограничиваться набором опций которые выбирает клиент. Поверьте, я бы объяснил подробней, просто это такая стена текста была бы. Желательно что-то совместимое с wordpress

Answer (score 0):

На первый взгляд, все это, и ещё многое другое, есть в плагине [Events Manager](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/events-manager/)